nodejs/ts app on azure app service keeps shuting down after start
I have an app service on azure, a nodejs/ts/express api, until today I could just push and it was on prod, today I pushed and since then the app keeps stopping every time I try to start it. I don't understand as I didn't touch any config on azure, I made the code was ok and even replicated the env to try it on another machine and it worked (I can't replicate perfectly an azure env as you can imagine but I tested something on a similar env)
Do any of you have seen this? how did you fix it pls?
here are some logs I found on azure (sorry, I tried to delete some but I don't know if it is needed so it is very long)
2024-06-24T08:26:32  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P19MeM6&sid=OYrQyh13hClsrJTIAAAC, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/6bf076983efa-39b5f92c-c437-4069-aea3-18adde228e8b.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/6bf076983efa-39b5f92c-c437-4069-aea3-18adde228e8b.txt)
2024-06-20T13:45:26  Startup Request, url: /api/settings, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/88c8a4642956-c24a1941-8740-4fa7-aaa9-ca3609e75734.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/88c8a4642956-c24a1941-8740-4fa7-aaa9-ca3609e75734.txt)
2024-06-20T12:58:50  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,14, ScmType: None/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9d16c2dd755d-48b0cdc7-f953-47a6-94f2-3d3e76abf238.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/9d16c2dd755d-48b0cdc7-f953-47a6-94f2-3d3e76abf238.txt)
2024-06-20T09:58:00  Startup Request, url: /webssh/webssh2.css, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/ad8f0c2465a0-eb92cda2-4a3a-46c9-a50b-cb75778e3352.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/ad8f0c2465a0-eb92cda2-4a3a-46c9-a50b-cb75778e3352.txt)
2024-06-20T13:21:05  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_03ed90fb36-7ef871f6-3e22-4105-9b8c-0682b81e6cff.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_03ed90fb36-7ef871f6-3e22-4105-9b8c-0682b81e6cff.txt)
2024-07-02T10:13:14  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,89, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_11213d1cb9-15d326b5-12ea-4918-863c-89861092adbb.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_11213d1cb9-15d326b5-12ea-4918-863c-89861092adbb.txt)
2024-08-05T13:58:54  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 91,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_1d16d7f308-4c499241-95a4-4957-abaf-8adaa3f498a8.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_1d16d7f308-4c499241-95a4-4957-abaf-8adaa3f498a8.txt)
2024-08-05T14:12:16  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_215d961b0f-3a37c59e-c639-46a6-8592-9c23bce30d53.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_215d961b0f-3a37c59e-c639-46a6-8592-9c23bce30d53.txt)
2024-07-23T13:09:40  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_3570aa6bb5-3f3be6eb-fc2d-47e5-bc79-ffd1dc8f6252.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_3570aa6bb5-3f3be6eb-fc2d-47e5-bc79-ffd1dc8f6252.txt)
2024-06-28T08:07:51  Startup Request, url: /api/logs/docker, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_39c2e6939c-50d8d577-b2d3-41fa-afdb-d53ee005bec6.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_39c2e6939c-50d8d577-b2d3-41fa-afdb-d53ee005bec6.txt)
2024-08-05T13:11:19  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4a8e367ea8-d74bcb27-5ee1-49f9-8d1e-476a7e18ef2d.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4a8e367ea8-d74bcb27-5ee1-49f9-8d1e-476a7e18ef2d.txt)
2024-08-05T13:54:54  Startup Request, url: /logstream, method: GET, type: request, pid: 91,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction
2024-08-05T13:55:54    Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: ProcessRequest end
2024-08-05T13:55:55  Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: Inside Reset/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4c7640eaea-15a647b6-82d8-4257-b9bd-a9a91251b7c1.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4c7640eaea-15a647b6-82d8-4257-b9bd-a9a91251b7c1.txt)
2024-07-23T14:16:02  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,61, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4df9832002-0660ca71-d066-4597-b343-b694658833d1.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_4df9832002-0660ca71-d066-4597-b343-b694658833d1.txt)
2024-06-20T09:36:30  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_516b19334c-08efbd58-2d55-4a21-a4a1-3a6a7b704483.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_516b19334c-08efbd58-2d55-4a21-a4a1-3a6a7b704483.txt)
2024-06-28T08:04:41  Startup Request, url: /api/logs/docker, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_60a9d4f603-89945fb4-c8ac-43a0-a41b-2f983a015cec.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_60a9d4f603-89945fb4-c8ac-43a0-a41b-2f983a015cec.txt)
2024-08-05T13:49:24  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P4YpKGH&sid=vwOodSOzaaonf-btAAAA, method: POST, type: request, pid: 93,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_61752d2a65-e9b42de0-5383-4602-ae9a-871a5491bff9.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_61752d2a65-e9b42de0-5383-4602-ae9a-871a5491bff9.txt)
2024-06-26T14:17:45  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?%24orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&%24top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6704ae0cb2-eb37450c-7c84-4d6b-b724-cedf00407cac.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6704ae0cb2-eb37450c-7c84-4d6b-b724-cedf00407cac.txt)
2024-06-27T07:51:24  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,16, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6aaf8b0e6b-088e615d-7d9a-4120-99ad-0f9bacae3f1c.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6aaf8b0e6b-088e615d-7d9a-4120-99ad-0f9bacae3f1c.txt)
2024-06-28T07:33:26    Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: ProcessRequest end
2024-06-28T07:33:26  Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: Inside Reset/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6aaf8b0e6b-2cde56cb-2504-4faf-ad40-c953359e3393.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_6aaf8b0e6b-2cde56cb-2504-4faf-ad40-c953359e3393.txt)
2024-06-28T07:30:16  Startup Request, url: /logstream, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,3, ScmType: GitHubAction
2024-06-28T07:33:16    Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: ProcessRequest end
2024-06-28T07:33:16  Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: Inside Reset/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_7636b0a66e-aef228b0-8d63-4973-9ee0-eaac13465748.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_7636b0a66e-aef228b0-8d63-4973-9ee0-eaac13465748.txt)
2024-06-20T09:55:32  Startup Request, url: /webssh/host, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,16, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_81cb57fc35-6688a2bd-6aaf-4636-a0d3-a38aedaaaf3b.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_81cb57fc35-6688a2bd-6aaf-4636-a0d3-a38aedaaaf3b.txt)
2024-06-20T09:57:38  Startup Request, url: /webssh/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P0r58ym&sid=nVZn6bzbht66RgGbAAAC, method: POST, type: request, pid: 87,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_8d36457090-60581346-61b6-47c0-ad25-33d59ab85502.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_8d36457090-60581346-61b6-47c0-ad25-33d59ab85502.txt)
2024-08-05T14:21:44  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_919507d814-263da97a-c55a-4b8a-887c-fc72b08ab026.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_919507d814-263da97a-c55a-4b8a-887c-fc72b08ab026.txt)
2024-08-05T14:48:58  Startup Request, url: /webssh/host, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_9632e3296e-60d06115-fa53-438c-9260-eeaa6fb54fbb.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_9632e3296e-60d06115-fa53-438c-9260-eeaa6fb54fbb.txt)
2024-07-05T08:05:31  Startup Request, url: /api/settings, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,25, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_98fcf4693f-d6c7593b-2242-4a0a-85af-a2647c2d84b9.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_98fcf4693f-d6c7593b-2242-4a0a-85af-a2647c2d84b9.txt)
2024-06-26T14:28:17  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,18, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_a1bace32b9-68b0fb41-94ae-4107-855b-ebc66778990f.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_a1bace32b9-68b0fb41-94ae-4107-855b-ebc66778990f.txt)
2024-07-29T10:35:14  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 91,1,34, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_b6eb3739df-2425e1c9-5c6e-43dc-9e39-699bbe4505cc.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_b6eb3739df-2425e1c9-5c6e-43dc-9e39-699bbe4505cc.txt)
2024-08-05T14:51:17  Startup Request, url: /webssh/host, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_c4988782f2-da1cc621-881f-49e0-9cc0-6f1792683ba9.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_c4988782f2-da1cc621-881f-49e0-9cc0-6f1792683ba9.txt)
2024-08-05T13:35:04  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 93,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ceedece9da-b094cc52-1027-422a-8932-ab0431176e93.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ceedece9da-b094cc52-1027-422a-8932-ab0431176e93.txt)
2024-07-02T14:45:06  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,31, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_cefdb37411-1d42d7ee-05ab-42f9-ae39-ca1dd6c8c3b8.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_cefdb37411-1d42d7ee-05ab-42f9-ae39-ca1dd6c8c3b8.txt)
2024-08-05T13:28:33  Startup Request, url: /api/logstream/, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,21, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_d844958bd8-e997eea9-a9c3-499d-ac22-4db5da140344.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_d844958bd8-e997eea9-a9c3-499d-ac22-4db5da140344.txt)
2024-08-02T06:41:08  Startup Request, url: /webssh/host, method: GET, type: request, pid: 91,1,7, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ddbc7a3427-4466cc9c-4842-4e1c-a095-dedb7a1c6f9f.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ddbc7a3427-4466cc9c-4842-4e1c-a095-dedb7a1c6f9f.txt)
2024-06-26T14:42:30  Startup Request, url: /, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,5, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_e13f62e263-84ca8b8b-c437-4cbd-9dff-74d0e86419c2.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_e13f62e263-84ca8b8b-c437-4cbd-9dff-74d0e86419c2.txt)
2024-06-20T09:39:28  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 86,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ed01eb6b57-ebaaaf85-56ae-455c-bdb1-206edd1b30ee.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_ed01eb6b57-ebaaaf85-56ae-455c-bdb1-206edd1b30ee.txt)
2024-08-05T13:53:37  Startup Request, url: /logstream, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction
2024-08-05T13:54:38    Error occurred, type: error, text: LogStreamManager: ProcessRequest end/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_efcba1ae8c-b80b7c60-b865-4532-ab64-fd5565194267.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_efcba1ae8c-b80b7c60-b865-4532-ab64-fd5565194267.txt)
2024-06-28T07:22:05  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_f2c00ab493-7eb6a4fd-4818-4c5a-9be8-e7c568e3e84d.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_f2c00ab493-7eb6a4fd-4818-4c5a-9be8-e7c568e3e84d.txt)
2024-06-28T08:14:58  Startup Request, url: /api/logs/docker, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,19, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_f3736e4d4e-f4937bdb-5bff-450d-8a8a-de8528995ff7.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/api-bamboo_kudu_f3736e4d4e-f4937bdb-5bff-450d-8a8a-de8528995ff7.txt)
2024-06-27T08:37:39  Startup Request, url: /api/settings, method: GET, type: request, pid: 92,1,14, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/kudu/trace/c0db1e245a5a-e572e91b-b988-492c-a4d8-e8a455a53985.txt  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace/c0db1e245a5a-e572e91b-b988-492c-a4d8-e8a455a53985.txt)
2024-06-24T10:51:14  Startup Request, url: /api/deployments/?$orderby=ReceivedTime%20desc&$top=20&api-version=2022-03-01, method: GET, type: request, pid: 87,1,70, ScmType: GitHubAction/home/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_default_docker.log  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_default_docker.log)
2024-08-05T14:52:06.0234357Z fi
2024-08-05T14:52:06.0234398Z
2024-08-05T14:52:06.0244834Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm run start
2024-08-05T14:52:06.6383503Z npm info using npm@10.5.0
2024-08-05T14:52:06.6388067Z npm info using node@v20.14.0
2024-08-05T14:52:06.9200769Z
2024-08-05T14:52:06.9201963Z > api_bamboo@1.0.0 start
2024-08-05T14:52:06.9202044Z > node build/index.js
2024-08-05T14:52:06.9202170Z
2024-08-05T14:52:07.0857586Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 249ms/home/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_default_scm_docker.log  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_default_scm_docker.log)
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4353359Z       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4353419Z       System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357106Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception , Boolean , HttpResponseMessage , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken , CancellationTokenSource )
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357207Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken )
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357237Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy.ProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357268Z          at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 97
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357302Z          at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 103
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357334Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
2024-08-05T14:51:23.4357367Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
2024-08-05T14:54:12.8169118Z Deploy Async/home/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_docker.log  (https://api-bamboo.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_08_05_ln0sdlwk0000C4_docker.log)
2024-08-05T14:51:56.7846274Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b808fadb/stderr_c058f2c0d05a432bbea637739997f058.
2024-08-05T14:51:56.7846919Z Creating container with image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-05T14:52:05.1036742Z Starting container: api-bamboo_b808fadb.
2024-08-05T14:52:05.1760385Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-05T14:52:05.1766090Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-05T14:52:05.1770923Z Container is running.
2024-08-05T14:52:07.9268672Z Container start method finished after 14789 ms.
2024-08-05T14:54:28.8127167Z Container start method called.
2024-08-05T14:54:28.8214095Z Establishing network.
2024-08-05T14:54:28.8219108Z Pulling image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod.Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---Starting Live Log Stream ---
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3406891Z Container is starting.
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3417705Z Establishing user namespace if not established already.
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3420445Z Establishing network if not established already.
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3423423Z Mounting volumes.
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3427204Z Nested mountpoint site/wwwroot
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3538066Z Nested mountpoint volatile/logs
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3565520Z Nested mountpoint
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3587914Z Nested mountpoint
2024-08-05T14:54:30.3644352Z Nested mountpoint
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3327483Z Creating container.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3338469Z Creating pipes for streaming container io.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3347993Z Creating stdout named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stdout_e3da9644409249f29b418503960c0cd0.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3357433Z Successfully created stdout named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stdout_e3da9644409249f29b418503960c0cd0.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3366816Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stdout_e3da9644409249f29b418503960c0cd0 for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3375121Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stdout_e3da9644409249f29b418503960c0cd0.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3383442Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stdout_e3da9644409249f29b418503960c0cd0.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3392636Z Creating stderr named pipe at /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stderr_5ee0f38b58c24c4280d75037561ebb9f.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3401617Z Successfully created stderr named pipe at: /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stderr_5ee0f38b58c24c4280d75037561ebb9f.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3414168Z Opening named pipe /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stderr_5ee0f38b58c24c4280d75037561ebb9f for reading in non-blocking mode.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3422833Z Successfully opened named pipe: /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stderr_5ee0f38b58c24c4280d75037561ebb9f.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3435975Z Successfully removed non-blocking flag from /podr/container/pipe/api-bamboo_b64fd1aa/stderr_5ee0f38b58c24c4280d75037561ebb9f.
2024-08-05T14:54:32.3446042Z Creating container with image: appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod from registry: mcr.microsoft.com and fully qualified image name: mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/node:20-lts_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3458753Z    _____
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3626324Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3628148Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3629484Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3630749Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3631992Z         \/      \/                  \/
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3633243Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3657349Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3658593Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3659770Z NodeJS Version : v20.14.0
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3661015Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3663730Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3665002Z WEBSITES_INCLUDE_CLOUD_CERTS is not set to true.
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3666283Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3667699Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3669025Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3670411Z Build Operation ID: d7fb079a-6f01-4ee9-875a-135e5f572f12
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4206312Z Environment Variables for Application Insight's IPA Codeless Configuration exists..
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4347016Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4583901Z Running #!/bin/sh
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585071Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585129Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585212Z export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585252Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585310Z        export PORT=8080
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4585351Z fi
2024-08-05T14:54:41.4589744Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm run start
2024-08-05T14:54:41.8660948Z npm info using npm@10.5.0
2024-08-05T14:54:41.8670152Z npm info using node@v20.14.0
2024-08-05T14:54:42.1785537Z > api_bamboo@1.0.0 start
2024-08-05T14:54:42.1785693Z > node build/index.js
2024-08-05T14:54:42.3243449Z npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 227ms
2024-08-05T14:54:40.3615141Z Starting container: api-bamboo_b64fd1aa.
2024-08-05T14:54:40.3907290Z Starting watchers and probes.
2024-08-05T14:54:40.3919944Z Starting metrics collection.
2024-08-05T14:54:40.3923089Z Container is running.
2024-08-05T14:54:41.3446930Z Container start method finished after 12523 ms.
2024-08-05T14:54:45.4156352Z Terminated
2024-08-05T14:54:45.3855376Z Container is terminating. Grace period: 5 seconds.
2024-08-05T14:54:45.3884483Z Stop and delete container. Retry count = 0
2024-08-05T14:54:45.3885495Z Stopping container: api-bamboo_b808fadb.
2024-08-05T14:54:45.4460658Z Deleting container: api-bamboo_b808fadb. Retry count = 0

Here is my github action file
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - api-bamboo

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "20.x"

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: "Deploy to Azure Web App"
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: "api-bamboo"
          slot-name: "Production"
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_B013E4C6329E49F293BBDD882BC40899 }}
          package: .

    terraform_job:
        needs: build_deploy
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        env:
            ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
            ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
            ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
            ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
            RESOURCE_GROUP: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
            APIM_NAME: ${{ secrets.APIM_NAME }}
            STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME: ${{ secrets.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}
            CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ secrets.CONTAINER_NAME }}
            KEY: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
        steps:
        - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

        - name: Set up Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v3.1.1

        - name: Initialize Terraform
        working-directory: ./terraform
        run: terraform init -migrate-state -backend-config='resource_group_name=${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}' -backend-config='storage_account_name=${{ env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }}' -backend-config='container_name=${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}' -backend-config='key=${{ env.KEY }}'

        - name: Validate Terraform
        working-directory: ./terraform
        run: terraform validate

        - name: Refresh Terraform
        working-directory: ./terraform
        run: terraform refresh -var='resource_group_name=${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}' -var='apim_name=${{ env.APIM_NAME }}'

        - name: Plan Terraform
        working-directory: ./terraform
        run: terraform plan -var='resource_group_name=${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}' -var='apim_name=${{ env.APIM_NAME }}'

        - name: Apply Terraform
        working-directory: ./terraform
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve -var='resource_group_name=${{ env.RESOURCE_GROUP }}' -var='apim_name=${{ env.APIM_NAME }}'

Here my index.ts file:
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
import routes from './routes';
import DbBamboo from './classes/db/dbBamboo';
import ShopifyWebhooksManager from './classes/shopify/shopifyWebhooksManager';

void (async (): Promise<void> => {
  dotenv.config();

  try {
    // La première connexion prend plus de temps que les suivantes
    const db = DbBamboo.getInstance();
    await db.connect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to connect to database');
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  try {
    const shopifyWebhooksManager = new ShopifyWebhooksManager();
    await shopifyWebhooksManager.subOrUpdateWebhooks();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to subscribe/update shopify webhooks');
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  const app = express();
  const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT ?? '3000', 10);

  app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  app.use('/', routes);

  app.listen(port, () => { if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`); });
})();


could you please share your repo if possible? Check in kudu that your file is available in wwwroot folder.

how you are deploying your expressjs app, github/zip/azuredevops/vscode/ any other method?

Hi, it is a private repo of my job, but the files are indeed in the wwwroot folder, and the app starts, I can confirm that because at the beginning of the app I subscribe to webhooks on shopify and the webhooks are created.
I am deploying with the file by default from azure github action, I only deleted the artifact part to do everything in 1 job, I'll add my github action file in my question

I have just seen this in the logs after restarting again today
2024-08-06T06:58:39.2404443Z chown: changing ownership of '/temp': Operation not permitted
2024-08-06T06:58:39.2433013Z chmod: changing permissions of '/temp': Operation not permitted
does it have something to do with anything? In my app I don't use temp folder but maybe the container of azure or something

from where you are taking your build artifact to deploy in package? As Far As I package: .  work on the build artifact. it will look root directory for the files.

I don't think I understood the question but yes I want to deploy everything so I make it look to the root and as I said I removed the artifact part to make everything in 1 job

I think that is why it is throwing error.  upload artifact creates a artifact with all the files created using npm install and npm run build.  and download artifact all the files during deployment and creates deploys to web app.

do you have node_modules folder in repo?

Yes I have, the artifact is only used in github to pass the files from 1 job to another, I deleted the second job to do everything in 1 job. But I found something else that I think is weird, I can do my calls from azure's default url by I can't from my apim, I can call https://api-bamboo.azurewebsites.net/ but not https://api-bamboo-apim.azure-api.net I don't understand it's like they are not related anymore, I'm going to look this way

have you configured your APIM in Azure app service in portal

Somehow my apim was not related to my api anymore so this question has no sense, thanks @Vivek Vaibhav Shandilya for your time, this question can be deleted I guess.
